# Doublebuffer winforms panel issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to double buffer a winforms panel element. I use the panel for drawing shapes. Right now, I have something along the lines of:

```
class BufferPanel : Panel {
    public BufferPanel() {
        this.DoubleBuffer = true;
    }
}
```

Mouse movement triggers the panel Refresh(). Some shapes are drawn in when Paint is triggered This is where I have a problem. These shapes are only drawn for a split second after mouse movement triggers a Refresh, then completely vanish. It's like they are only drawn on one buffer or something along those lines. This appears to only happen with Paint. For example, I can copy/paste the shapes into the mouse move method, and everything will work fine. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using the `e.Graphics` object from the `Paint` event or `OnPaint` override.  Avoid using `CreateGraphics`.  Try posting your painting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted from comment:

> Sounds like you aren't using the e.Graphics object from the Paint event or OnPaint override. Avoid using CreateGraphics.